# SetFrameCenterRotation cause movement issues in NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

I asked the following question one hour ago:

[Rotating NSImageView cause the NSImageView to scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640723/rotating-nsimageview-cause-the-nsimageview-to-scale)

I found the solution to a rotation issue by rotating the NSView:

```
[self setFrameCenterRotation:-priorResult];
[self setFrameCenterRotation:rot];
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

This works just as I want it but when I try to move the NSView by setting the frame:

```
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(prect.xPos, prect.yPos, prect.w, prect.h)];
```

The frame won't move correctly. I read about CALayer and Core Animation, but I don't understand it, does anyone have a simple solution for my problem?